# Problem with Scanner and a letter "Ł" in text - JAVA

Tags: java, encoding, java.util.scanner

I have a problem with Scanner. In doc.txt there is a letter "Ł" (its from polish alphabet). Scanner skips the part with this letter and scans only the part before. There is probably a solution, but I'm a newby in coding… Can you help? Fragment of the code is below.

```
File file = new File("doc.txt");
String tempTest = "";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    tempTest = tempTest.concat(sc.nextLine() + "\n");           
}
sc.close();
```

Comment: Use locale while trying to read a file, and set the encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Change your scanner line as new Scanner(file, "utf-8");

Comment: How did you create the file? Do you know what character encoding it uses?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your file is encoding in `UTF-8`. If you use for example Notepad to create your file the default encoder is ANSI which do not support Polish letters.

To change the encoding of a file created in Notepad:

1. Open your file in Notepad
2. Under tab `File` press `save as`
3. Press the drop down list just left of the `Save` button in the lower left corner
4. Choose `UTF-8` as your encoder in the drop down list
5. Save your file